# Extracting all data from a DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset

In my program of retrieving data from database for a certain criteria, I have created a method which returns a DataSet. I want to read all the rows present in that DataSet. I cannot use ExecuteReader in this context. A `foreach` loop is the right approach but I'm not able to figure out the syntax for that.
`GetDataSet("SearchNumberSP", dictionary);` returns `DataSet d1;`
The DataSet has only 2 columns. Please help me to figure this out!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You could try;
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]; 
foreach(dr in ds)
{
GetDataSet("SearchNumberSP", dictionary); 
}

Comment: Its not working for me. i will edit the question to show where am using and how i need it. Thank you @GuinnessIsLife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dataset has between zero and (theoretically) infinite DataTables and those have between zero and (theoretically) infinite Datarows/DataColumns.

It doesn't make sense to say that the DataSet has only 2 columns because DataSet has no property called DataColumns.
Thus, it doesn't make sense to return a Dataset if you're only looking for a single table, you should return a DataTable.

If you're insisting on returning a Dataset (which represents a full database), the code to parse that would look something like this:

```
foreach (DataTable table in _dataset)
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
    {
         foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
         {
              Console.Writeline([dataColumn].ToString());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. the Dataset has only one table in it and that table has only 2 columns @Fang

Comment: @ananthreddy: I'm aware of that. My point is that if you're only working with one table anyway, there's no need to use a Dataset.